# Как посчитать с помощью COUNT() с 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли с такой схемой БД реализовать запрос, который выводит количество Триллеров у каждой студии и если у студии нет триллеров, нужно чтобы выводился 0?

[image: Схема БД]

```
 SELECT 
        Studios.StudioName,
        Count(Genres.GenreName) AS [Count-GenreName]
    FROM ((Genres
        INNER JOIN FilmsGenres ON FilmsGenres.GenreID=Genres.GenreID)
        INNER JOIN Films ON FilmsGenres.FilmID=Films.FilmID)
        INNER JOIN Studios ON Films.StudioID=Studios.StudioID
    GROUP BY Studios.StudioName, Genres.GenreName
HAVING (((Genres.GenreName)='Thriller'));
```

С помощью этого кода удалось Получить следующий результат:

```
[StudioName]        [Count-GenreName] 
[20 Century Fox]    [1]
[Syncopy]           [2]
```

А нужно получить:

```
[StudioName]        [Count-GenreName] 
[20 Century Fox]    [1]
[Syncopy]           [2]
[Universal Studios] [0]
[Quad]              [0]
```

Пробовал использовать LEFT OUTER JOIN или RIGHT OUTER JOIN, но к результату это не привело.

Comment: Зачем нужна таблица FilmsGenres, не проще хранить ид жанра в таблице Films?

Comment: @Haswell очевидно, у фильма может быть одновременно несколько жанров, например "фантастика" и "комедия".

Comment: @Yaant, я уже понял. Для меня фильмы имеют один жанр) либо комедия либо ужасы)

Comment: `FROM studios LEFT JOIN films LEFT JOIN filmsgenres LEFT JOIN genres`

Comment: @Akina, тоже пробовал, к сожалению не работает.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но "не работает" - это [censored]. Запрос либо завершается ошибкой (какой?), либо даёт результат, возможно неверный. Всё, иных вариантов не существует.

Comment: @Akina если использовать конкретно Вашу строку, то выходит ошибка синтаксиса из-за отсутствия ON.
Если же написать:FROM ((Studios
    LEFT JOIN Films ON Films.StudioID=Studios.StudioID)
    LEFT JOIN FilmsGenres ON FilmsGenres.FilmID=Films.FilmID)
    LEFT  Genres ON Genres.GenreID=FilmsGenres.GenreID
То результат такой же как в вопросе.

Comment: Не `Count(Genres.GenreName)`, а `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @ArchDemon, выдает такой же результат, как и в вопросе.

Comment: *если использовать конкретно Вашу строку* :facepalm: Я указываю порядок связывания таблиц! А не даю окончательный текст запроса - предполагается, что Вы понимаете, что делаете, и легко доведёте запрос до рабочего состояния.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, с JOIN к таблице Studios получается результат без 0.

```
SELECT Studios.StudioName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Films
        LEFT JOIN FilmsGenres ON FilmsGenres.FilmID=Films.FilmID
        LEFT JOIN Genres ON Genres.GenreID=FilmsGenres.GenreID
        WHERE Films.StudioID=Studios.StudioID AND Genres.GenreName='Thriller') AS total
    FROM Studios;
```

Этот запрос рабочий. Проверял лично. Работает не сильно быстро. Может кто предложит более быстрый вариант.

Для небольшого ускорения можно не присоединять Genres и в условии ставить `FilmsGenres.GenreID=X` (где X - номер жанра триллер)